# When I get a document do I also get sub-collections?

Tags: firebase, collections, google-cloud-firestore, document

When I get a document from my Firestore database, are also sub-collections returned?

If I have a document "user" and a subcollection "Messages", if I ask for user info I don't want message to be returned, I don't want to pay for useless infos and slow down my app

Comment: No, queries are shallow.

Comment: No, you only get the document.